# Why the "if constraint" not working in the code?

Tags: c

The first if statement is not working  and code is running without considering the constraint.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)

    {
      int with;
     int inacbal;
     float acleft;
     scanf("%d",&with);
     scanf("%d",&inacbal);
     if(0<=with<=2000&&0<=inacbal<=2000)  //this statement not working
    {
     if((with%5)==0)
    {
        if(inacbal>with)
        {
         acleft=(float)inacbal-(float)with-0.50;
         printf("%.2f",acleft);
        }
    else
         printf("%d",inacbal);
    }
    else
      printf("%d",inacbal);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Even on inputting value greater than the constraint relation the loop is running.

Comment: `if(0<=with<=2000&&0<=inacbal<=2000)` C doesn't work that way. Go read a book.

Comment: A general comment. People with vision problems cannot read your code. The cramming of variables with operators makes this all but impossible to see. White space is your friend. It provides separation making it easier to read.

Comment: People without vision problems will also find your code unreadable and this lands you a poor first impression as a programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While mathematicians sometimes use the shorthand `a < b < c`, the C language is a bit more strict.

You must rewrite:

```
if(0<=with<=2000&&0<=inacbal<=2000)
```

to be something like:

```
if((0 <= with) && (with <= 2000) && (0 <= inacbal) && (inacbal <= 2000))
```

What you have actually *is* valid C but it does not do what you would normally expect. The expression `1 < 2 < 3` actually means: calculate `1 < 2` (giving the integral truth value `0` or `1` for false and true respectively) then comparing *that* against `3`.

If you *want* to use a shorter form, you can use something like:

```
#define between(a,b,c) (((a) <= (b)) && ((b) <= (c)))
:
if (between (0, with, 2000) && between (0, inacbal, 2000))
```

though you need to watch out for duplicated side effects if you use terms such as `a++` when using it. A safer approach may be replacing the macro with something along the lines of:

```
int between (int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a <= b) && (b <= c);
}
```

Comment: @Newbie, I've explained that in the latest update. It's a logic error rather than a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
if(0<=with<=2000&&0<=inacbal<=2000)
```

is not checking variables between the given range. These comparisons doesn't have mathematical meaning in C.
Compiler should raise a warning

```
[Warning] comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]
```

To check whether a value is between a given range or not you need to use `&&` operator. You need to rewrite it as

```
if(0 <= with && with <=2000 && 0 <= inacbal && inacbal <=2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare avariable to two other values like that. You should separate the conditions:

```
if ((0<=with) && (with<=2000) && ( 0<=inacbal) && (inacbal<=2000))
```